# Returning wrong maximum sum sub array(kadane's algorithm), but correct maximum sum

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Given below is my code for the kadane's algorithm in Python 2.7 for returning the maximum sub array. Although, i'm getting the correct maximum sum(MSS variable) ,for the given example list,
it's returning the wrong sub array. Could someone please explain to me why ?

```
A = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
M = max(A)
L = len(A)
if(M < 0):
   print M
ans = []
subans = []
MSS,subsum,i = 0,0,0

while(i<L):
   subans.append(A[i])
   subsum = sum(subans)
   if(subsum<0):
       subans=[]
       i+=1
   else:
       if(subsum>MSS):
           MSS=subsum
           ans=subans
           i+=1
       else:
           i+=1
print ans
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output

Comment: Expected output [4,-1,2,1] with MSS =6
However i get [4,-1,2,1,-5,4]

Comment: why are you using an else and increasing i in each block when you always increase i regardless? You might want to look at `range` and learn about `elifs's`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because when you do -

```
ans=subans
```

You are just storing the reference of `subans` to `ans` , when you change something within `subans`, the changes also reflect in `ans` (as they are the same reference).

You need to store a copy of `subans` in `ans` , instead of the direct reference.

Example -

```
ans = []
subans = []
MSS,subsum,i = 0,0,0

while(i<L):
   subans.append(A[i])
   subsum = sum(subans)
   if(subsum<0):
       subans=[]
       i+=1
   else:
       print('subsum - ' + str(subsum))
       print('MSS - ' + str(MSS))
       if(subsum>MSS):
           MSS=subsum
           ans=list(subans) #more ways to do this, like subans[:] also works, and copy.copy(subans) , etc.
           i+=1
       else:
           i+=1
```

Comment: when would `subans[:]` not work when `list(subans)` would?

Comment: it would, when did I say it wouldn't ? I said `like subans[:] may also work`

Comment: *may also work*, do  you understand the meaning of *may*?

Comment: `may` is not a negative, I just use `may` most of the places. Do you want me to re-word it?

Comment: It is worded as if `list(...`  will always copy a list and `[:]` might not when both will do exactly the same making a shallow copy of the list and fail with nested objects, where a deepcopy would then be needed

Comment: I have reworded it to be less ambiguous , though I believe `may` indicates that i am not 100% sure rather than partial working of the other.

Comment: may indeed does mean not 100 percent sure in the context but [:] would work or not work exactly as list(... would or not  so if may applied to [:] it should also apply to list(...,  a  less ambiguous way would have been to distinguish the difference between shallow and deep copying. list(... and [:] are exactly the same as far as copying goes.

Comment: I did not go into those details as it was not needed for the OP's issue, OP is using a list of integers, so shallow copying is good enough.

Comment: There are a  million dupes of this question, if you don't want to give a thorough answer you should probably flag it as a dupe then